# JAXB Output XML Attributes to be desired order

Tags: jaxb

I am using JAXB classes for writing xml. While marshalling the order of attributes to be displayed in our desired order. Please suggest to solve this one.

My Current Output:
 <ELD UID="1000" Designation="SUPERSTRUCTURE" Code="11">

Required Output:
 <ELD UID="1000" Code="11" Designation="SUPERSTRUCTURE">

Comment: What is the order of element attributes based on?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what JAXB implementation you use, if you're willing to use MOXy then it's possible to implement [DescriptionCustomizer](https://community.oracle.com/thread/977397?tstart=0).